# VC++ -- This declaration has not storage class or type specifier

Tags: c++, inheritance

I get this erorr: VC++ -- This declaration has not storage class or type specifier in the line:

```
towerControl.push_back() = new Boeing;
```

Can somebody point out what's going wrong? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Aircraft {
public:
    virtual void disp() { cout << "I'm an aircraft\n"; }
    virtual ~Aircraft() { cout << "Aircraft::Destructor\n"; }
};

class Boeing: public Aircraft {
public:
    void disp() { cout << "I'm a Boeing\n"; }
    ~Boeing() { cout << "Boeing::Destructor\n"; }
};

class Airbus: public Aircraft {
public:
    void disp() { cout << "I'm an Airbus\n"; }
    ~Airbus() { cout << "Airbus::Destructor\n"; }
};

class Tower {
public:
    vector <Aircraft*> towerControl;
    towerControl.push_back() = new Boeing;
    towerControl.push_back() = new Airbus;
    ~Tower() { cout << "Tower::Destructor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Tower T;
}
```

Comment: What you need is a good book to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
towerControl.push_back(new Boeing);
```

And you also need to call it inside a member of `Tower`, possibly a constructor:

```
class Tower {
public:
    vector <Aircraft*> towerControl;
    Tower()
    {
       towerControl.push_back(new Boeing);
       towerControl.push_back(new Airbus);
    }
    ~Tower() { cout << "Tower::Destructor\n"; }
};
```

Seems to me like you need to start learning the basics of C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
towerControl.push_back() = new Boeing;
towerControl.push_back() = new Airbus;
```

The `push_back()` function of vector does not return anything. All it does is accept a parameter to be pushed into the vector. So you are literally setting nothing in the push_back() statement.

```
towerControl.push_back(new Boeing);
towerControl.push_back(new Airbus);
```

Should work just fine.

PS: Is assignment at that part of the class declaration possible? Err....

Comment: Not really. You can't just write statements in the class definition and expect them to work. They need to be in context. See my answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Edited :) Editing took time.